# The same CSS animations does not have the same durations (with animated background color)

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation

I try to animate two blocks with css animation. Its have the same `transform` animation but one of it has `background-color` animation also. This animations splitted to two `@keyframes`.

See code (https://codepen.io/mctep/pen/Rgyaep):

```
<style>
   .a {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      animation: a 1s infinite;
    }

    .b {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: gray;
      animation: b 1s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes a {
      0% {
        background-color: red;
        transform: translateX(0);
      }

      50% {
        background-color: green;
        transform: translateX(100px);
      }

      100% {
        background: red;
      }
    }

    @keyframes b {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }

      50% {
        transform: translateX(100px);
      }
     }
</style>

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Animation of colored block is lag from gray block In Google Chrome. In Safary and FF it works perfectly.

I can to make one `@keyframes` for `background` and other for `transform` and it solves problem. But I want to use single value of `animation` property for single element. If there are no any ways to fix it I'll separate `moving` and `coloring` animations.

Why this happens? Is it Google Chrome bug?

Comment: transform: translateX100px); isn't correct, do you saw ?

Comment: @Pv-Viana thank you, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't give you a concrete reason *why* this happens, but we can un-confuse Chrome by simply specifying a `background-color` in animation B as well.

```
@keyframes b {
  0% {
    background-color: gray; /* add this */
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```css
.a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: a 1s infinite;
}
.b {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  animation: b 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes a {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: green;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
  }
}
@keyframes b {
  0% {
    background-color: gray;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```